# file upload php $_FILES undefined index error

Tags: php, file, upload, indexing, undefined

```
<?php

$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
//$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
//$type = $_FILES['file']['type']


$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if (isset ($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

    $location = 'uploads/';

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'Uploaded';    
        }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
          }
    }
?>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i get an 'Notice: Undefined index' error message. The enctype is included in the form tag so i can't figure out what it is.. can anyone help me out??

Comment: Is your entire code inside one file, or are they split into two seperate files?

Comment: @Fred -ii- in single , 200%

Comment: I agree. I was about to post an answer to that affect, but it's already been taken care of below. @voodoo417

Comment: Actually, I changed my mind. I posted a working copy below. @voodoo417

Answer (score 10):

The first assignment throws an warning, if nothing is uploaded and the isset test is a little bit useless..

You can change your code as follows

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    if (!empty($name)) {
        $location = 'uploads/';

        if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
            echo 'Uploaded';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'please choose a file';
    }
}
?>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks! the undefined index error is gone but now i get this error:

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/testhoes.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/upload.php on line 14.

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnvksz8' to 'uploads/testhoes.jpg' in /var/www/upload.php on line 14

Comment: sorry the errors above are 2 errors but i dont know how to put space between them

Comment: The upload directory must exist and have write permissions (i.e. 755)

Answer (score 5):

Resolved Undefined Index in php while uploading file
due to maximum file size limit
changes in `php.ini`

```
`max_execution_time` = 300  
`max_input_time` = 240  
`post_max_size` = 128M
`upload_max_filesize` = 128M
```

change according to your requirements

Comment: Thank You @Randeep Singh

Comment: Location inside xampp: xampp/php/php.ini

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> /* mistake here: change test.php to your source: upload.php */
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using your entire code as **one file** (which I suspect you are), then you need to do the following using a conditional statement, which I tested (and working) before posting.

Plus, make sure that your `uploads` folder has proper write permissions set and it exists.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
//$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
//$type = $_FILES['file']['type']

$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if (isset ($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

    $location = 'uploads/';

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'Uploaded';    
        }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
          }
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

I added a conditional statement:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

and I named the submit button: (to work in conjunction with the [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) conditional statement)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

---

**N.B.:** If you are in fact using your posted code as two seperate files, then you can simply copy the PHP in this answer, along with naming your present submit button set in a seperate HTML form as `name="submit"` (calling your form `upload_form.htm` for example) as I did shown above, yet retaining the `action="upload.php"` and naming the PHP upload handler file accordingly.

Comment: just like the answer from phillip the undefined index error is gone. Thanks!

Comment: but now i get this error: Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/testhoes.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/upload.php on line 14.
                                                                      
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnvksz8' to 'uploads/testhoes.jpg' in /var/www/upload.php on line 14

Comment: Does the folder exist and is it writeable? @user3221348 meaning, does it have the proper write permissions?

Comment: You haven't answered my question. @user3221348

Comment: the tmp/ folder or the upload/ folder?

Comment: The `uploads` folder. Not `upload`. Your code has the word in plural form. @user3221348

Comment: I take it that since I haven't heard from you in the past 5 mins. that it's working. @user3221348

Comment: i can put a file in the folder with wincsp. does that mean i have permission? sorry im a newb

Comment: Are you trying to do this via the Web, or on a local machine? Plus, the folder needs to be `chmod 755` or `777` in order to write in it. @user3221348

Comment: no sorry im trying it on different places on the server.. its a assignment for the university of amsterdam and we are working in a group. there is a directtory /var/www on which the website will be and every member of the group has their own folder in which they can work which is /home/michael. I tried them in both folders. there is a tmp folder in /var.

Comment: You will need to use a folder then that you can upload to. However, you still haven't answered my original question. Does the `uploads` (in plural form) folder exist? @user3221348

Comment: im doing it trough the web with winscp. the server is at the university.

Comment: oh sorry that folder exist in the same place as the php file exists

Comment: OK. Have you tried using a regular web browser to run the PHP file? I can't see why you're using `winscp` to do this. And maybe the University isn't allowing uploading. @user3221348

Comment: im using winscp to upload the php and html files to the server and then im using the chrome browser to run the files..

Comment: the university told us to use winscp or filezilla to upload our php and html files to the server..

Comment: sorry im really new to this.. just started with webdevolping course 2 weeks ago

Comment: Ok, well you should find out if the University only allows you to upload files via FTP. They might not be allowing for uploaded files via a script, in maybe thinking that it could be a breach of security; that's what I think may be happening. Also, as a last resort, you can try changing the `uploads/` setting to `/var/www/home/michael/uploads/` or something to that affect, yet I doubt it will work. @user3221348

Comment: I get the same error with the /var/www/home/michael/uploads/ path.. But thanks a lot for your help! I will check it with the university tomorrow. its 1.30 in the morning here now. I'll let you know what the problem is.

Comment: Ok and you're welcome. Let me know if that's the case, I'd be curious to know. And ask them, if you can use an uploading form to upload files via the Web, and what you need to use as the setting for it. @user3221348

Comment: it turns out you were right about the chmod 777. I had to change the folder into it. Thank again for your help @Fred -ii-

Answer (score 1):

```
1. You hadn't mention name value in your submit button.
2. Use isset function.

<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>



<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

echo $name;


//$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
//$type = $_FILES['file']['type']


$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

if (isset ($name)) {
    if (!empty($name)) {

    $location = 'uploads/';

    if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
        echo 'Uploaded';    
        }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
          }
    }
}       
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Count total files
$countfiles = count($_FILES['event_Img']['name']);
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $filename = $_FILES['event_Img']['name'][$i];

    // Get extension
    $ext = end((explode(".", $filename)));
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['event_Img']['tmp_name'][$i], "uploads/".$filename);
    $sqlBrand = 'INSERT INTO ot_event_images 
                SET 
                event_id=:event_id, 
                imagepath=:imagepath, 
                imagemimetype=:imagemimetype';
    $query2 = $conn->prepare($sqlBrand);
    $query2->bindParam(':event_id', $eventid);
    $query2->bindParam(':imagepath', $filename);
    $query2->bindParam(':imagemimetype', $ext);
    $status2 = $query2->execute();
}
if($status2)
{

    echo "File upload successfully";
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```