# Submit two forms in one event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I have this `onclick` event that serializes some form data and saves it to a variable, when the user runs another function I want to be able to send that previously created variable through ajax in the function.

Here is the `onclick` event (first form):

```
$('#new_shout_next').on('click', function () {
    var new_shout_slide_1_form = $("#new_shout_form").serialize();
});
```

Here is the function that is performed after the `onclick` event, so hopefully you can get what I mean (second form):

```
function uploadFile(){

    var file = _("new_shout_upload_pic").files[0];


    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("new_shout_upload_pic", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "scripts/dashboard/dash_new_shout_upload.php");

    var new_shout_slide_1_form = $("#new_shout_form").serialize(); //This is the edit i have made and removed this line of code from the on click event above
    ajax.send(formdata, new_shout_slide_1_form);

}
```

And just in case you need it here is the `dash_new_shout_upload.php`:

```
     $fileName = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["name"]; 
     $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["tmp_name"];
     $fileType = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["type"];
     $fileSize = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["size"]; 
     $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["error"];

     $new_shout_text = $_POST['hiddenNewShoutText']; //This is one of the fields in the serialized form first created in the onclick event.
```

Here is the error I get in the console:

> `Uncaught ReferenceError: new_shout_slide_1_form is not defined`

Sorry if this is a bit confusing, basically the short story is that I want to be able to submit two forms in one event, so my idea was to save the first form and submit it with the second one.

Thanks and let me know if you need anything else.

**EDIT**

Ok basically musa has given me this code below

```
 function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("new_shout_upload_pic").files[0]; 
    var formdata = new FormData($("#new_shout_form")[0]);// add new_shout_form fields to the formdata object
    formdata.append("new_shout_upload_pic", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "scripts/dashboard/dash_new_shout_upload.php");

    ajax.send(formdata);

}
```

Which will obviously work better as it will send both the `new_shout_form` data along with the uploaded file. The problem is i can't seem to access the `new_shout_form` fields in the php script, i can access and get the file ok such as this `$fileName = $_FILES["new_shout_upload_pic"]["name"];` However, i am not sure how to get the field in the `new_shout_form` into variables. I have tried `$new_shout_text = $_FILES["dash_new_shout_location"];` and `$new_shout_text = $_POST["dash_new_shout_location"];` However i get the error `Undefined index: dash_new_shout_location` Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**

This is an edit for Musa's recent comment here are the two forms, the first is the first one the users submit with the text inputs and the second one is the file.

First form, when this is submitted the textarea div content is set to the hidden input, then the second form is diplayed for the user to select the file/image

```
        <form id="new_shout_form">      

                        <div class="dash_new_shout_content">
                                <div id="dash_new_shout_textarea" name="dash_new_shout_textarea" class="dash_new_shout_textarea" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Write your shout..."></div>
                                <input id="hiddenNewShoutText" name="hiddenNewShoutText" type="hidden"></input>
                        </div><!--end dash_new_shout_content-->

                        <div class="dash_new_shout_options">
                            <input name="new_shout_next" type="button" id="new_shout_next" class="new_shout_finish" value="Next" alt="Next" />
                            <div class="dash_new_shout_cancel" id="new_shout_cancel">Cancel</div><!--end dash_new_shout_cancel-->   
                        </div><!--end dash_new_shout_options-->

            </form>
```

Form 2 with the file upload, when this one is submitted i want it to send the inputs from form 1 with it.

```
<form id="new_shout_2_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">


                <div class="dash_new_shout_content">

                    <div id="dash_new_shout_new_pic">
                        <img id="new_shout_img" src="#" class="new_shout_img" width="100%" />           
                    </div><!--end dash_new_shout_new_pic-->

                    <div class="dash_new_shout_content_option_pic"> 
                        <div class="dash_new_shout_pic_file_upload_wrapper">
                            <input name="dash_new_shout_pic_name" id="new_shout_upload_pic" type="file"  /><span id="dash_new_shout_pic_file_upload_span">Upload from Computer</span>
                        </div><!--end dash_new_shout_pic_file_upload_wrapper-->     
                    </div><!--end dash_new_shout_content_option-->

                </div><!--end dash_new_shout_content-->
                <br style="clear: both">

                <progress id="new_shout_image_progress_bar" value="0" max="100" style="width:80%;"></progress>
                <div id="progress_status">0%</div> 
                <div id="new_shout_image_status"></div> 
                <div class="dash_new_shout_options">

                    <input name="new_shout_finish" type="button" id="new_shout_finish" onclick="uploadFile()" class="new_shout_finish" value="Finish" alt="Finish" />
                    <div class="dash_new_shout_cancel" id="new_shout_back">Back</div><!--end dash_new_shout_cancel-->

                </div><!--end dash_new_shout_options-->
            </form><!--end new_shout_2_form-->
```

Comment: Why not just append the variables of the second form to the first one instead of creating a new one?

Comment: How would I do that, I didn't know you could append twice

Comment: Did you check if the file is actually uploading? Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271060/file-upload-php-files-undefined-index-error 
Also specify your enctype to multipart/form-data

Comment: Yes the file is uploading fine, the problem is I can't seem to get the data in the text inputs in the other form

Comment: Post the form with the fields you want to upload.

Comment: I have added the two forms for the input fields and the file form in the second edit in my original post

Comment: You have no field named `dash_new_shout_location` in `new_shout_form` only `hiddenNewShoutText` did you mean to use that instead?

Comment: It looks like you aren't setting the method for `new_shout_form` to POST. Might that be the issue? Otherwise the default is GET.

Comment: Yh there are loads of inputs too many to post.

Comment: So the only field in `new_shout_2_form` is the file field?

Comment: Yes about 4 text inputs in form 1 and one file input in form 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just get the data when you are going to post it, get all the data in the upload function

```
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("new_shout_upload_pic").files[0]; 
    var formdata = new FormData($("#new_shout_form")[0]);// add new_shout_form fields to the formdata object
    formdata.append("new_shout_upload_pic", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "scripts/dashboard/dash_new_shout_upload.php");

    ajax.send(formdata);

}
```

Comment: Hi, i have added the line you said and removed the new_shout_slide_1_form from the .send as it was giving error, but i now get this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` Any ideas?

Comment: I have found that it is this line in the php file `$new_shout_text = $_FILES["dash_new_shout_location"];` which is the line to one of the variables of the `new_shout_form` form which you added above to the form data, i don't think i am getting the variable correctly

Comment: What would I need to do in the php script to access the new_shout_form variables?

Comment: OK, i managed to get it working using your code above, basically i had to do some remodelling of the setup i had for the forms, i took some ideas from others below and submitted the first form for all the post data, then took the id of the post and set it to a hidden input in the file upload form, where if the user wanted to add an image, they could so seperately, so i used the code above to send both a text input and the file in the same http request, thanks all for this pretty lengthy question

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to define  `var new_shout_slide_1_form = '';` outside your on event, then inside the on event just `new_shout_slide_1_form = $("#new_shout_form").serialize();`. This will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem. The best thing you can do is this:

-- Submit data form as normal ajax and return the mysqlID
-- Use that to submit second form in the callback of the first

BELIEVE ME: it's going to save you a lot of headache

Comment: The problem is the user first enters the Text data such as names etc.. First and then goes and selects the image, so what happens if they disconnect or decide to cancel between the two forms, I would be left with just one of the forms submitted

Comment: simple: register the profile as incomplete and let them come back to the image upload phase. Not all users upload photos, some never do it, other don't care so much. making it optional will help you

Comment: I used your answer to remodell my form setup so along with other peoples answers i managed to get it working, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your FormData object is not working correctly.

```
 var formdata = new FormData($("#new_shout_form")[0]);// add new_shout_form fields to the formdata object
formdata.append("new_shout_upload_pic", file);
```

The reason the "new_shoud_upload_pic" is working is because it is explicitly defined.

A method to test this theory is to use var_dump on the $_POST variable and see what data is being posted.

```
<?php
   //show $_POST index values
   var_dump($_POST);...
?>
```

If the post values don't exist, then you know the problem is in the HTML, but it could be that one of the name fields in the form is misspelled.

If indeed the $_POST global variable doesn't contain your form field name and values, there is a problem in the FormData object.

You can try replacing the jQuery method by using document.getElementById. Another possible solution would be to manually loop through the fields in the form and append them to the FormData object.

This [Mozilla Developer Site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) gives some instruction and samples of how to use FormData and pass with an XMLHttpRequest as well as looping through the form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so complicated?

```
function checkForm(button) {

      formOk = false;

      if (button = 'first') {
        //check form
        if (formOk) myform.submit();
      }

      if (button = 'second') {
        //check form using other logic
        if (formOk) myform.submit();
      }

    }


    <input type="button" onClick="checkForm('first');" value = "button 1">
    <input type="button" onClick="checkForm('second');" value = "button 2">
```

Comment: is there anyway not to do them seperately, the action i am trying to do with the 2 forms is basically like a post, one form is the image in the post and the other form is all the post text etc... so i would rather submit them together if possible

Answer (score 0):

Simple just add a closure!

```
$(function(){
var new_shout_slide_1_form  = "";

$('#new_shout_next').on('click', function () {
    new_shout_slide_1_form = $("#new_shout_form").serialize();
});

function uploadFile(){

    var file = _("new_shout_upload_pic").files[0];


    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("new_shout_upload_pic", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "scripts/dashboard/dash_new_shout_upload.php");


    ajax.send(formdata, new_shout_slide_1_form);

}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save data in cookies:

```
document.cookie = "key1=value1;key2=value2;expires=date";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kick of two AJAX calls on two concurrent threads to simultaneously submit each of the forms.  You will have to implement the Concurrent.Thread JavaScript library, which is free and open source towards this end.

You can download it from here:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsthread/index.php?title=Main_Page

Tutorial explaining the use of the library can be found here:
http://www.infoq.com/articles/js_multithread