# 'Undefined index' When trying to upload photo?

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image from a form, however I keep getting the error: Undefined index: file

```
<form action ="upload.php" method="post">
<label for="name">Image</label>
<input type="file" id="title" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And then in upload.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($file_name){
    move_uploaded_files(file_tmp_name,"uploads/$file_name");
    }
}
```

Changed $_POST['submit'] to $_POST['file'] however I get the same error. Thanks

Comment: Set  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form attribute, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271060/file-upload-php-files-undefined-index-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add enctype in your form

```
 <form  action ="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and then In your PHP code use name instead of image with $_FILES.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if($file_name){
move_uploaded_files(file_tmp_name,"uploads/$file_name");
}
}
```