# php uploading file, says undefined index, not sure why

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to upload an image. I have included the form from a different page (inc/pages/addRecipe2.php) and the form loads fine and I am running the code for the form in the same page (addRecipe/?token=...), when I try to upload the file it says that there is an undefined index: image

the errors I am getting:
[image]

form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/file-data" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">
        </div>
        <?php
        if ($privateRecipe == "public") {
            echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' style='width: 100%' id='finishRecipe' name='finishRecipe'>Submit recipe for review</button>";
        } else {
            echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' style='width: 100%' id='finishRecipe' name='finishRecipe'>Complete reci</button>";
        }
        ?>
        <p class="formMessage1"></p>
    </form>
```

php code, running the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['finishRecipe'])) {
$recipeId = $_GET['token'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];

$imageName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$imageTmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imageSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$imageError = $_FILES['image']['error'];
$imageType = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$fileExt = explode(".", $imageName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
$allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');


if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowedExt)) {
    if ($imageError === 0) {
        if ($imageSize < 500000) {
            $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
            $fileDestination = "uploads/$fileNameNew";
            move_uploaded_file($imageTmpName, $fileDestination);
        } else {
            echo "The image is too big!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There was an error with your image!";
    }
} else {
    echo "File type not allowed!";
}
```

}

it does echo out "file type not allowed" as one of my error messages I made.

Any solutions?

Comment: The extension of the file you've uploaded is not 'png', 'jpg' or 'jpeg' ? `$allowedExt = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');`

Comment: what is the value of `strtolower( end( $fileExt ) )`

Comment: I have updated the post with the errors I am getting - in the image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file upload php $\_FILES undefined index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271060/file-upload-php-files-undefined-index-error)

Comment: @EthanPatchell whats value of $imageName?

Comment: @Rp9 it's suppose to be ['image']['name'] but its saying that image is undefined, and I'm not sure why that is

Comment: change enctype of form  enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @Rp9 you're actually kidding me! How can that tiny thing create such an annoyance... thanks!

Comment: @EthanPatchell i will post this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first change the enctype to form-data

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

and then check

```
if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowedExt)) {
            if ($imageError === 0) {
                if ($imageSize < 500000) {
                    $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
                    $fileDestination = "uploads/$fileNameNew";
                    move_uploaded_file($imageTmpName, $fileDestination);
                } else {
                    echo "The image is too big!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "There was an error with your image!";
            }
    } else {
        echo "File type not allowed!";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is generated may be your file size bigger than default max_upload size.

So please change it in your php.ini:

```
`upload_max_filesize` = 128M
```

or other option to resolve this error is check that image name set or not.

```
    if (isset($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {

        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

        if (!empty($name)) {
           $location = 'uploads/';
           if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
               echo 'Uploaded';
            }

        } else {
          echo 'please choose a file';
        }
    }
```

Comment: what I mean is, it says that "image" is undefined, that's the error I am getting. how do I fix that?

Comment: @ethan patwell did you try with 1st solution?

Comment: Yes, same error, the error is undefined index: image

Comment: the form is on a different page, which I have included in the main file

Comment: can you change form attribute  `enctype="multipart/file-data"` to  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?